# Changing the buckets for dc histogram with d3 domain call

Tags: javascript, d3.js, histogram, dc.js

I have a histogram I am creating with `dc`.  And on the bar chart I have the following

```
.x(d3.scale.linear().domain([-5,5]))
```

And this does create buckets in that range but it does so at a pretty coarse level (integers to be exact).  Is there a way to have it use finer grained buckets, ideally I think around .2 would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `.ticks()` call on the xAxis. I use [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js), rather than [dc.js](/questions/tagged/dc.js), but looking at the docs I think that something like this should work:

```
.xAxis().ticks(50)
```